# Use a dynamically calculated value as a param

Tags: javascript

If I have 2 objects that look like this

```
const var1 = { employee_id: employeeID }
```

and

```
const var2 = {employee_id: 4}
```

I need to do something like this

```
const testFunc = (param) => {
  console.log(param)
}

testFunc(var2.var1.employee_id)
```

so that the output would be

```
employeeID: 4
```

How can i frankenstien an object refernce out of two seperrate object keys/values?

Edit: The solution i was looking for was to use `var2[var1.employee_id]`

Comment: `var2.var1.employee_id` is undefined because `var1` is not a property of `var2`.

Comment: Explain your use case in more detail

Comment: based on your question title and content I believe you're probably overthinking whatever it is you're trying to do. Perhaps explaining the situation would make it more clear.

Comment: The problem I'm having is this. _var2.var1.employee_id_ <- doesn't make sense. That's not how objects work.

Comment: I know thats not how objects work. I am not expecting my example code to work. I was just using it as a kind of example to show what i am trying to accomplish

Comment: Sure. is this what you're looking for? `var2[var1.employee_id] = var2.employee_id`  -> it will give you `var2[employeeID] = 4`

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank you! can you tell me what this concept is called? I've only ever used brackets like that to access a specific child in an array

Comment: @ChristopherMellor whenever you want to access any  property of objects dynamically  you need to use [] square bracket notation.

Comment: _How can i create frankenstien_ - what is Frankenstein supposed to mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i was looking for was to use `var2[var1.employee_id]`

Answer (score 0):

```
const testFunc = (var1, var2, parameter) => {
  console.log(`${var1[parameter]} : ${var2[parameter]}`)
}

testFunc(var1, var2, 'employee_id')
```

Something like that !

If you just want to create the object `{employeeID : 4}` from `var1` and `var2` the function should be

```
const testFunc = (var1, var2, parameter) => {
  return {var1[parameter] : var2[parameter]}
}
```

If you know you have the same and unique parameter on the two objects you can simplify :

```
const testFunc = (var1, var2) => {
  const parameter = Object.keys(var1)[0]
  return {var1[parameter] : var2[parameter]}
}
```

Comment: I can't use a string value for what `parameter` is, i need it to be the actual key of the object

Comment: @ChristopherMellor that you can achieve with just a small tweak in the above answer instead of string use Object.keys(var1)[0]